# Wrong home dir in sftp

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp

I set up an sftp server with openssh but when I connect to it I cannot browse my folder. The answer to pwd command is: /
and to ls command is: remote readdir("/"): Permission denied    [added after request in comments]

What is my error? 
Here is my configuration:

Added in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Added to /etc/passwd:

```
rezzato:x:1001:1001:rezzato,,,,:/media/data/ftp/rezzato:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Added to /etc/group:

```
ftpaccess:x:150:rezzato
rezzato:x:1001:
```

Answer to $ groups rezzato:

```
rezzato : rezzato ftpaccess
```

Answer to # ls -la /media/data/ftp:

```
drwxr-----  3 root root 4096 set  3 08:51 rezzato
```

Answer to # ls -la /media/data/ftp/rezzato:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 rezzato ftpaccess 4096 set  3 08:51 ftp
```

Thank you for your support,
Matteo

Comment: How are you connecting to it?

Comment: sftp rezzato@localhost from same machine

Comment: `The answer to pwd command is: /` -- What is wrong with this? You are chrooted so you see the directory `/media/data/ftp/rezzato` as `/`. If you can `ls` in that directory or upload/download, everything is ok. If not, provide more error messages.

Comment: Well, actually I though that was an error but ok, it's not.
Nevertheless the problem is that if I give ls command I get the answer:
remote readdir("/"): Permission denied

Comment: uff.. is this a so complex problem?  
Please help, I'm trying to setup an ftp server at home but unsuccessfully